# jQuery AJAX in IE7 and IE8 refreshes the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to submit a form through ajax using GET method. It works fine in FF, CHROME and other browsers except IE7 and IE8. I am using jQuery 1.6 and I am validating the form using [jQuery Validation Plugin 1.10.0](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js)

Form is getting validated but when I try to submit it refreshes the page instead of AJAX. In console its not displaying any error

Heres my JS Function

```
function formSubmit(formID, displayMssgID) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        var qstring = $('#' + formID).serialize();
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
              return this.optional(element) || value != param;
            }, "Please enter your name.");
        var val = $('#' + formID).validate( {
            rules : {
                Mobile : {
                    number : true,
                    minlength : 8
                },
                Name: {
                    required: true,
                    notEqual: "Name"
                }
            }
        }).form();
        if (val) {
            $('.overlayss').fadeIn();
            $('#prospectLoading').fadeIn();
            $('#prospectLoading').append('<div class="process_img"> Registering your Request ...<br />Please Wait ...</div> ');
            $.ajax( {
                url : "index.php",
                data : qstring,
                cache:false,
                success : function(data) {

//                  resetFormFields(formID);
                    if(formID == 'siteVisit'){
                        $('#cart ul').html('');
                    }

                    //$('#' + displayMssgID).html('');
                    $('#prospectLoading').html('');
                    $('#prospectLoading').append(data);
                    //$('#' + displayMssgID).append(data);                  
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#prospectLoading').html('');
                        $('.overlayss').fadeOut();
                        $('#prospectLoading').fadeOut();
                    }, 4000);                   
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

You can check the live example on this link http://www.silverline-group.com/projects/Bangalore-Properties.html

Fill up the form on the right sidebar in IE7 or IE8.

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is the validation plugin causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had same problem in IE7 when i used Jquery validation plugin 1.10.0 for my form control validation.
name attribute is not required for it to work anymore.

[JQUERY PLUGIN VALIDATION](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Another important thing,**ID** and **Name** must be specified for the elements you are validating as well as for the form and submit button. While **FF** and **Chrome** works without these, **IE doesn't**.

The tab-out validation does work without the name, but not the form submit validation.

Comment: I have already included name, id attributes. I am still facing the same problem, did you get any solution to this?

Comment: i have written my own validation script for all controls.jst lemme know if u want that.